# How to loop through a dataframe and get value of corresponding column?

Tags: r

I'm trying to loop through a dataframe and get values of two columns. But they get printed twice.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, 
  "a", 2,  
  "b", 1
)
```

```
for(i in df) {
  print(paste(df$x, "occurs", df$y, "time[s]"))
}
```

Output

```
[1] "a occurs 2 time[s]" "b occurs 1 time[s]"
[1] "a occurs 2 time[s]" "b occurs 1 time[s]"
```

How do I make it print only once and in a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the rows of the dataframe and use it to subset the dataframe to get every row output separately.

```
for(i in seq(nrow(df))) {
  print(paste(df$x[i], "occurs", df$y[i], "time[s]"))
}

#[1] "a occurs 2 time[s]"
#[1] "b occurs 1 time[s]"
```

As I understand this is just an example to do something else, otherwise `paste` is vectorised and you'll not need loop to just print the content. This can work directly.

```
paste(df$x, "occurs", df$y, "time[s]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `writeLines` function

```
for(i in 1:dim(dummy)[1]) {
  writeLines((paste(dummy$x[i], "occurs" , dummy$y[i], "time[s]", "\n")))
}
```

result:

```
a occurs 2 time[s] 

b occurs 1 time[s]
```

Comment: @TyperWriter I made a mistake.  I edit my code.

Answer (score 1):

A combined answer inspired by @Park and @Ronak Shah:

```
writeLines(paste(df$x, "occurs", df$y, "time[s]"), sep = "\n")
```

```
a occurs 2 time[s]
b occurs 1 time[s]
```